# Linux: SyntaxError for error-free Python script

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to run a python file that works fine on my Windows machine on a remote server:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import shelve
import cloudpickle
import numpy as np
import typing
from typing import List

import ray
from ray.rllib.agents import ppo
from ray.rllib.utils.spaces.space_utils import flatten_to_single_ndarray
from ray.tune import register_env
from ray.rllib.env.base_env import _DUMMY_AGENT_ID
from ray.rllib.policy.sample_batch import DEFAULT_POLICY_ID

.
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WIN = False
    ray.init(dashboard_port=8263)
    daterange = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=35040, freq='15T')
    norming_factor = 10  
    actions_module = ActionsModuleContinuous()
    batch_n_days = 1
    kappa = 1000
    seed = 1234
    steps_per_episode = batch_n_days * 24 * 4
    num_episodes = 5
    
    device_config: List = list()
    device_config.append(Device1(WIN=WIN, norming_factor=norming_factor, n_data_points=steps_per_episode))
    device_config.append(Device2(WIN=WIN))
    device_config.append(Device3(WIN=WIN))
```

It returns the following SyntaxError, for no apparent reason:

```
(venv) [<username>@<server> examples]$ python test.py
  File "test.py", line 183
    device_config: List = list()
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried deleting `: List`, which just had the effect of moving the same error to a seemingly arbitrary place further down the script. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of Python on your remote machine? I assume its < 3.5. Read [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Answer (score 1):

`device_config: List = list()`

That syntax is adding type annotations for variable device_config.

If you get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` exception, it means that your python interpreter used to run your code is not new enough. Nothing to do with your code, it just means that when you enter `python` in your shell, interpreter that gets executed is not new enough.